# GTV 3.2 channels API change?

Tags: google-tv

[An article](http://gigaom.com/video/google-tv-honeycomb-32/) on GTV 3.2 says "Improvements to the way Google TV identifies channels will make it easier for app developers..."

What channel change is this referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see https://plus.google.com/u/1/107226127526541403399/posts/L6QWuDmcpp9

**Google TV - Latest release Now on Sony**

**Important Features**
• Honeycomb 3.2 (API Level 13)
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.2.html
• Chrome works faster
• Support for 3D content
• HLS works better
• Extensions to the Channel Listing Content Provdier
• Hardware Acceleration is turned on

**Channel Listing Content Provider**
- new column to ChannelListingContract, "DATA_SOURCE" example "TMS"
- new contract for exposing lineups for each device, MediaDeviceContract

Formal documentation should be up in a few days.

**Hardware Acceleration**
 
and all it’s kin now works.

For more information see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

This platform change has caused a few apps to misbehave. Please re-test your apps on this release. (We’ve also updated the M4’s aka if you have one of those).

**How do I have two apk’s?** 
(One that runs on hardware that hasn’t yet updated, and one that runs on the new hardware - if needed)

The new APK should have:

Market will be able to accept multiple apk’s, and deliver the right one to your tv.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html for more information.